# Probability of having a set of the same color when picking $N$-sets of $3$ items from $2$ + neutral colored bag of balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Having a bag of balls of $3$ colors:

- $m$ balls are red
- $n$ balls are blue
- $o$ balls are grey

If $N$ people pick $3$ balls out of the bag, what is the probability that at least one of them will have $3$ either red or blue balls.

The probability of one person doing this should be:
$\frac{\binom{m}{3} + \binom{n}{3}}{\binom{m+n+o}{3}}$

I cannot figure out the case with multiple people, because those are not independent events.

Comment: Assuming you want *at least one* of them will have 3 red or 3 blue balls, then apply inclusion-exclusion on the events $R_1,R_2,R_3,\dots,R_N,B_1,B_2,\dots,B_N$ where $R_i$ is the event that the $i$'th person selected three red balls and $B_i$ is the event that the $i$'th person selected three blue balls.

Comment: @JMoravitz How would I calculate the probabilities? It depends on the remaining balls.

Comment: $Pr(R_1)=\frac{\binom{m}{3}}{\binom{m+n+o}{3}}$ as I'm sure you should already understand.  Similarly $Pr(R_i)=Pr(R_1)$ by just pretending the $i$'th person cut in line to take their balls first (*this can be made more formal, but it works the same as how, say, the second card in a deck has a $\frac{1}{52}$ chance of being an ace of spades, just as the first card does*).  $Pr(R_1\cap R_2)=\frac{\binom{m}{3}}{\binom{m+n+o}{3}}\cdot\frac{\binom{m-3}{3}}{\binom{m-3+n+o}{3}}$, etc... seen by applying multiplication principle: $Pr(R_1\cap R_2)=Pr(R_1)Pr(R_2\mid R_1)$.  Continue